# How can I use first of type or first child to target only the top level one. Not the nested one?

Tags: css, css-selectors

Hello I want to target class = 'section',
How can I use first of type or first child to target only the top level one. Not the nested one?

```
    .site-content > .section-wrap > .section {
        margin-top: 1.5vmax;
    }


<div class="site-content">
    <div class="section-wrap">
        <div class="section">Target This</div>
        <div class="section">Target This</div>
        <div class="section">Target This
            <div class="site-content">
                <div class="section-wrap"></div>
                <div class="section">Not this</div>
            </div>
        </div>
        div class="section">Target This</div>
        div class="section">Target This</div>
        </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You won't be able to use :first-of-type or :first-child to target only the top level one and ignore the nested one.

Both these pseudo css selectors checks child for immediate parent.
[image]

For example, :first-of-type works as:
[image]

And :first-child works as:
[image]

Comment: I thought I can target the first site-content by using first of type

Comment: Yes, people often confuse with that behaviour. If you look at the above screenshot explaining :first-of-type, it still highlights 3 paragraphs. @BlueLi

Both of :first-of-type and :first-child is useful to select the immediate child of an element, and not any in the nested DOM.

Comment: @BlueLi If you think this answer helped, please do upvote and mark it as your answer. Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

If your posted HTML code is only wrapped by the `body` element, you can use this selector:

```
body > .site-content > .section-wrap > .section {
    margin-top: 1.5vmax;
}
```

If there's another element in between `body` and your first-level `.site-content`, include that in the selector, also using the `>` operator for *direct*  descendants.

Answer (score 0):

According to your markup

```
.site-content > .elementor-section-wrap + .elementor-section
```

if you don't want to select the nested one you do that by :not selector

```
:not(.site-content)  .site-content > .elementor-section-wrap + .elementor-section
```

Comment: I made a mistake for the markup, I updated the question. Please take a look again Thanks